# IP address rules for each octet

Tags: networking, ip, ipv4

This [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address#IPv4_addresses) on IPv4 addresses states the valid range for each octet is 0-255. However, when I enter a number that is deliberately out-of-range on my Windows 7 PC, the valid range is notified as 1-223 (not 0-255) for the 1st octet of my IP address:

[image: IPv4 first octet error message]

This applies to the first octet of `IP address`, `Default gateway`, `Preferred DNS sever` and `Alternate DNS server`, but not `Subnet mask`.  All other octets allow 0-255. We have some Windows CE 6.0 machines on-site and these allow 0-255 for all octets.

- Why does my Windows 7 machine report a valid range of 1-223 for the 1st octet only and why different to Windows CE?
- What are the rules for IP address octets?
- In writing a technical blog on IP settings, is it safe to assume a valid range of 0-255 (and ignore obscure restrictions) or should I be more subtle and cover some of the exceptions?

NB! I am not interested in whether the entered IP address will actually work...only the low-level rules for entering them in the first place!

Note: I asked our IT department. They did not know the answers and just directed me to Wikipedia!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An IPv4 address is just a 32-bit number, e.g. `00001010000010110000110000001101`. The decimal octet notation is just to make it easier for humans to read. Each octet is 8 bits, e.g. `00001010.00001011.00001100.00001101`, which is then converted to decimal numbers (`10.11.12.13`). Since 8 bits can represent the numbers from `0` to `255`, each octet can on have a number in that range.

The is nothing special or magical about the octet boundaries; they are artificial. Thinking of IPv4 addresses in terms of the textual representation (decimal octets) can really get you into some convoluted thinking and lead to errors. The computer and the network equipment only ever see and use the binary number. Many networking students want to manipulate IPv4 addresses without converting to binary first, and that is a path to failure.

The valid unicast IPv4 addresses go up to `223.255.255.255`. Addresses larger than that are multicast addresses (begin with `1110` as the first four bits of the address = `224.0.0.0` to `239.255.255.255`) or reserved (begin with `1111` as the first four bits of the address = `240.0.0.0` to `255.255.255.255`). The address `255.255.255.255` is the limited broadcast address.

[RFC 5735, Special Use IPv4 Addresses](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5735#section-4) has a summary of the IPv4 special use addresses.

Comment: Fine, that is consistent with my own research, but that answer doesn't address what those "artificial" boundaries are. On my Windows 7 PC, the range is defined by Windows as 1-223 but for a Windows CE PC on the same network, the range is 0-255 (both for octet 1). It looks like just saying "1-223" for octet 1 and no restriction for other octets is usual...other ranges are exceptions.

Comment: That has noting to do with the artificial boundaries of octets. A multicast address is one which starts with `1110` as the first four bits, and the reserved addresses start with `1111` as the first four bits.

Answer (score 2):

1-223 covers Class A/B/C networks, which are what your PC will use.

224+ is for Class D (Multicasting) and Class E (not used) networks, neither of which are appropriate for a Windows PC.

[Webopedia article on IP Addressing](http://www.webopedia.com/DidYouKnow/Internet/IPaddressing.asp)

Comment: Classful networking is dead, and it has been for over 20 years, killed by CIDR and VLSM (see RFCs 1518 and 1519 from the year 1993). Let it rest in peace.

Comment: Hmm, ok, thanks. I'm wondering how you would see what class of network you are entering an IP address for. The Windows 7 and Windows CE user interface look the same. What I'm really looking for is a concise description of the restrictions, if any, for the four octets of an IPv4 address. Would a reasonable catch-all for Windows PCs be 1-223 for octet 1 and 0-255 for the rest?

Comment: @AlainD: Yes. (assuming you are not validating input to an app that is setting up multicast networking)

Comment: This article (http://www.routerfreak.com/cidr-vs-vlsm/) has a nice discussion of CIDR and VLSM (thanks Ron). However, what isn't immediately clear from that article is how CIDR/VLSM technology affects the valid range for the 1st octet of IP address fields.

Comment: @AlainD, what you need to look at are the first four bits of an address: Unicast addresses are from `0000` to `1101`, Multicast addresses start with `1110`, and Reserved addresses start with `1111`.